# python - OpenCV filter2D cvmat and numpy disparity

Tags: python, opencv

I have been using a Gabor kernel for a computer vision project, however, when I filter the kernel with the legacy cv.Filter2D function, I get weird results. The input is a numpy array as I prefer using the newer, cleaner code and I change the numpy array to cvmat via the cv.fromarray() method. The kernel was being treated as a cvmat only throughout.

But when I run the same program with cv2.filter2D and use the numpy array src image as input, with changes to my kernel generating code to give me a kernel as a numpy array, I get just the results that I expected which match the results I got using the C++ functions.

Can anyone explain to me why is there this difference in the 2 filter functions?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, so I don't know why the results are different. But if you are not aware, it is always recommended to use cv2 interface.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I have made it a point to use only the cv2 interface for the sake of forward compatibility.